# How to remove example?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-editor

I can see that users remove low quality/downvoted examples of other users, but I can't fugure out, how do they do it?

If I try to edit such an example and remove everything UI says I need to write a title and a body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little Flag icon next to the title, just two icons over from the Edit icon. Users handling that request should be able to delete it completely.

Comment: So I just can flag it, not review for deletion?

Comment: You flag it and then someone else has to act on that flag and suggest deletion. Then it ends up as a change for review.

Comment: Strangely enough, you're then able to approve that review even though you posted the flag that caused it to be created, and it also seems to need more than 1 accept unlike edits. So getting something deleted requires at least 3 people though I suspect the intention was that it would require at least 4.

Comment: I think this is due workflow generalization.